# Model and View issues on new install of Kohana 3.3.2 from newbie

Tags: view, wamp, kohana, kohana-orm

Im new to Kohana and am having the following issues on day 1:

Im using Kohana 3.3.2 with wampServer and I can get to the Hello World at localhost with no issues.

I have the Kohana install in the root of my www directory, so I set my base url in bootstrap.php as so:

```
 Kohana::init(array(
    'base_url'   => '/',
   ));
```

As I said, "hello world" loads fine at localhost

I turned on ORM and Database in the bootstrap as well

I made a file called User.php and saved it in application/classes/Model/User.php

Inside that I have:

```
   class Model_User extends ORM

    {

    }
```

As copied from a tutorial on the web

So appending to the welcome controller, under the output statement that creates hello world, i have:

```
$user = ORM::factory("User");
```

and I get the error:

```
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Model_User' not found
MODPATH\orm\classes\Kohana\ORM.php [ 46 ]
```

I know from looking around this page should be familiar to you all, and I saw all the stuff about it not being the right case and the underscores as path (ie Model_User is really Model/User) and I have checked all my cases and paths. Cant figure out whats going wrong

So I said, let me try and do a view, so I made application/views/myview.php

its got a standard html page in there with a couple of tags
    `<p>If you see me, the view loaded.</p>`

I went back into the welcome controller and commented out the above `ORM::factory` line (so it again just showed hello world)  and added from another tutorial on views:

```
 $this->request->response = View::factory( 'myview' );
```

and I get nothing but Hello World.

I think something must be wrong with my paths but I cant figure out what, Im hoping you guys can help.

Note: there is no .htaccess in play here as this is running locally and in fact I only just put wamp on this machine yesterday for testing kohana, so it should be just a clean fresh install.

Any words of wisdom Kohana gurus?
Much appreciated!

EDIT: here is the source of the welcome controller:

```
class Controller_Welcome extends Controller {

    public function action_index()
    {
        $this->response->body('hello, world!');



            $this->request->response = View::factory( 'myview' );

        //$user = ORM::factory("user");
     }
}
```

as described above, If I uncomment the ORM line, I get the error page, calling the view, i just get hello world.

Comment: Ive also changed all the instances of "User" to "user", the filename, the orm call to it, the class name - ive taken out "Model_" put it back in, no luck

Comment: I also notice this line when I put the original install.php file back in place, is there something i need to do for my WAMP to turn this on?: 
PECL HTTP Enabled Kohana can use the http extension for the Request_Client_External class.
cURL Enabled Pass

Comment: and another update, i went down one version of kohana, same setup v 3.2.3.1 and am having the same results. I thought it may be worth it as I saw in the zip file that the folders had lower case names(controller and model) while in the higher version its (Model and Controller)

Comment: Put your full code from controller, then it will be easier to check anything. Is it fresh install with hello word or you modified anything more that that what you told here?

Comment: It is a fresh install, I will post my code in a few minutes

Comment: controller source added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using default kohana files so just change this line:

```
$this->request->response = View::factory( 'myview' );
```

to:

```
$this->response->body(View::factory( 'myview' ));
```

And your view will render correctly.

Your model looks correct and it should work, it is working for me...
Check if you don't forgot about

```
<?php  ?>
```

tags in model.

Check also if you have enabled mod_rewrite in server settings.
Probably it will throw 404 error if disabled but it is worth to check...

Comment: Thank you, that worked for the view, what do you mean about the tags in the model? Can you be more specific?